# Where to store ConfigurableApplicationContext in a Java EE application?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee

I'm planning to port a Spring application to a Java EE environment. Just I'd like to use JSF as presentation layer (instead of Spring MVC). My question is: what is a safe place in a Java EE application where I can store the **ConfigurableApplicationContext**, so that I don't need to repeat this multiple times:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Would it be safe storing it in the Application's context of a Web application or maybe in a SingletonEJB ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are OK: for application context you need to create a ServletContextListener and in contextInitialized() method create Spring application context. For Singleton EJB, create initialization method and add @PostConstruct method.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CDI, then you could create a simple producer for creating one application instance of the ConfigurableApplicationContext. See the following example:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class SpringProducer {
     @Produces
        public ConfigurableApplicationContext create() {
            return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        }
        public void close(@Disposes final ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
            ctx.close();
        }
}
```

For a full example see this [Spring tutorial on WildFly](http://www.mastertheboss.com/spring/spring-jdbc-application-on-wildfly)